# dictionary does not give me unique Ids in python

Tags: python

I have the output of an elasticsearch query saved in a file. The first few lines looks like this:

```
{"took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {},
   "hits": {
      "total": 27,
      "max_score": 6.5157733,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "dbgap_062617",
            "_type": "dataset",
            ***"_id": "595189d15152c64c3b0adf16"***,
            "_score": 6.5157733,
            "_source": {
               "dataAcquisition": {
                  "performedBy": "\n\t\tT\n\t\t"
               },
               "provenance": {
                  "ingestTime": "201",                     
               },
               "studyGroup": [
                  {
                     "Identifier": "1",
                     "name": "Diseas"
                  }
               ],
               "license": {
                  "downloadURL": "http",                      
               },
               "study": {
                  "alternateIdentifiers": "yes",
                },
               "disease": {
                  "name": [
                     "Coronary Artery Disease"
                  ]
               },
               "NLP_Fields": {
                  "CellLine": [],
                  "MeshID": [
                     "C0066533",                        
                  ],
                  "DiseaseID": [
                     "C0010068"
                  ],
                  "ChemicalID": [],
                  "Disease": [
                     "coronary artery disease"
                  ],
                  "Chemical": [],

                  "Meshterm": [
                     "migen",                        
                  ]
               },
               "datasetDistributions": [
                  {
                     "dateReleased": "20150312",                        
                  }
               ],
               "dataset": {
                  "citations": [
                     "20032323"
                  ],
                  **"description": "The Precoc.",**                  
                  **"title": "MIGen_ExS: PROCARDIS"**
               },
               .... and the list goes on with a bunch of other items ....
```

From all of these nodes I was interested in Unique _Ids, title, and description. So, I created a dictionary and extracted the parts that I was interested in using json. Here is my code:

```
import json
s={}
d=open('local file','w')
with open('localfile', 'r') as ready:
    for line in ready:
        test=json.loads(line, encoding='utf-8')
        for i in (test['hits']['hits']):
             for x in i:
                  s.setdefault(i['_id'], [i['_source']['dataset']
                  ['description'], i['_source']['dataset']['title']])
        for k, v in s.items():
        d.write(k +'\t'+v[0] +'\t' + v[1] + '\n')
d.close()
```

Now, when I run it, it gives me a file with duplicated _Ids! Does not dictionary suppose to give me unique _Ids? In my original output file, I have lots of duplicated Ids that I wanted to get rid of them.
Also, I ran set() only on _ids to get unique number of them and it came to 138. But with dictionary if i remove generated duplicated ids it comes down to 17! 
Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but your question seems to be "Do Python dictionaries always have unique ids?" The answer is no. A dictionary is just an associative array and they have no idea what the id is in any other dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Fry
Then if I want to have unique Ids  along with title and description, what is the best way to do it? Is it ever possible to do that?

Comment: Why are you processing the output line by line? I would think you want to read the entire thing as one JSON object, something like `with open('localfile') as inp: d = json.load(inp)`

Comment: @chepner thanks for your comment. But I need to do this because otherwise python generates an error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'. But when I read it line by line. it is working.

Comment: Are you using `loads`, or `load`?

Comment: @chepner I am using loads, and I used the following to write json data. f.write(json.dumps(res).encode("utf-8"))
f.write(("\n").encode("utf-8"))

Comment: `loads` is the wrong function to read from a file object; use `load`. JSON is *not* a line-oriented format, and should not be processed line by line. Related, don't confuse a file that contains a series of JSON objects (which could be stored one per line) with a file that contains *a* JSON object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155940/discussion-between-user3026373-and-chepner).

Comment: If you want a unique ID, if you're using a database it will create it for you. If you're not, you'll need to generate a unique number or string. Depending on how the dictionaries are created, you could use the timestamp of when the dictionary was created, or you could use `uuid.uuid4()`. For more info on `uuid`, [here are the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique ID, if you're using a database it will create it for you. If you're not, you'll need to generate a unique number or string. Depending on how the dictionaries are created, you could use the timestamp of when the dictionary was created, or you could use uuid.uuid4(). For more info on uuid, [here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).